# How to prevent cookie auth from redirecting to login

Tags: asp.net-core

I am building an intranet site that uses  core web api as the backend and angular as the front end. Because the way the db and overall project structure was written, I have an unconventional way of authorizing users. I am grabbing the windows login name (not using identity or any login page), then comparing it to a list of authorized users I have in my db. I got the authorization handler working, however I am stuck on finding a way to prevent my policy from redirecting to a login page (none will exist). Instead of redirecting, I want to just get the 401 status code, so I can use Angular to do a notification

I've done various searches on google/ stack overflow, all the examples and solutions use either identity or token policies, I am not going that route, I am only using a fake cookie auth just to get my authorization policy to work

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddScoped<IChecklistRepository, ChecklistRepository>();
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("Angular", b=>
        {
            b.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin();
        }));
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            opt =>
            {
                opt.LoginPath = null;
                opt.AccessDeniedPath = null;
               // Does not do anything 

            });

        services.AddDbContext<SWAT_UpdateChecklistsContext>(opt => opt.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conn")));
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });


        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("AccessUser", policy => {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new UserAccess());


                });

        });

        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizedUser>();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little more digging and think I found my answer,

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            opt =>
            {

                opt.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                opt.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            });
```